# 2.0 is recognized as 20 on google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to run a script on a Google spreadsheet. The below is the code snippet:

```
var startRow = 2;
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
   sheet.getRange( startRow + i, 4).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
}
```

I expect that "EMAIL_SENT" appears from the 2nd row. But, instead, it appears from the 20th row. When I write out startRow using Logger, it appears as 2.0, instead of 2. I am guessing that 2.0 is recognized as 20 since I live in Finland, where the comma, rather than dot, is used as a radix point. Having said that, my language setting is set with Japanese where dot is used for a radix point. So, this interpretation isn't logical, but this is the only explanation I could think of. When I used

```
Math.round( startRow )
```

This didn't help, either. Could anybody suggest solution? Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `for (i in data)` try `for (var i=0;i<data.length;i+=1)`

Comment: actually the issue you have is not what you think. 2.0 is ne normal representation for an integer in the logger . The actual issue is that in your code the addition 2+0 gives 20 instead of 2 because the script does not recognize integers and assumes they are strings. Sandy's solution is a good way to avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: Others have answered the question, but just adding a best practice comment: don't add values to a sheet with individual get range…setvalue inside a loop in the long run its a slow pattern. Better to manipulate a single array representing the whole range in memory and then make a single write to the sheet.

Comment: Yes, Sandy's suggestion worked and thank you also for advice on a best practice on writing to the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but for some reason that type of loop does not create numbered index(`i`). So, your script reads   `startRow + i` is like saying 2 and `i`, not 2 plus `i`.

Your not seeing the number 20 you are seeing the number 2 with the index 0.

To change this, you can either use this type of loop.

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    sheet.getRange( startRow + i, 4).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
  }
```

Or you can just add `Number()` to the `i`

```
sheet.getRange( startRow + Number(i), 4).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
```

Comment: Sorry, was writing my answer when the other comments were submitted. I just said exactly what they said.